# How to open webView (in Main project) by clicking button on alertView (in dependency project (Zxing))

Tags: ios, zxing

I am a real noob in ios dev. Now i am working on my study project using Zxing.

I make my own project which included dependency third party libraries(Zxing).
Once I scan QRCode which contains with a URL inside, my project will call a class in Zxing library then alert an alertView.
After that, once I click open button on pop-up alertView, it would open that URL by activating Safari.

the code in Zxing looks like this:

```
//============================================================

- (void)openURL {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.URL]; //<===== open URL by    Safari browser.
    }


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    // perform the action

    [self openURL];
  }
}
//========================================================
```

However, my wish is I would like to open that URL in my own webView which constructed by Interface Builder in my "own project" NOT by Safari. Do you have any suggestions? What I have to code in (void)openURL {} ? I got stuck with this issue for 3 days and I now seem to be crazy [*p*]

Thank you very much for your advance help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

What i did to do this is that I make a new view controller which has webView in it. A property URLstring which get set when the OpenURL method starts. You have to implement delegate methods of webView if you need. The code that I am using is

**in WebViewCOntroller.h**

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{


IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
UIView *activityView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *buyProductLink;
@end
```

**in WebViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.buyProductLink]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[request release];
}
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

return YES;
}
- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

        [activityView removeFromSuperview];
} 

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

        [activityView removeFromSuperview];
        [activityView release]; activityView = nil;
}
```

In openURL method use

```
WebViewController *webViewVC = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
webViewVC.buyProductLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fibnochi. I really appreciate your help. I would try this tonight. :)

Comment: one question @fibnochi. I am so curious about calling WebViewController in openURL method. How can you call WebViewController(which is allocated in your main project) in openURL method (which is called in Zxing project)? 

Will the Zxing know .h file in the main project?

thanks for your advance answer.

Comment: I have not used Zxing library.But I think Zxing library does not have to know any viewController. Your Xcode project will handle every thing  for you. Any how you can use custom view which contains your webView and call it in OpenURL method.

Comment: I tried it but Zxing dependency project informed that 'No such file or directory'. I think that dependency project can not call back .h file in main project. ;(

Comment: I have not used zxing. You can achieve this functionality in the way you can by using this idea.